# HTML/CSS background color

Tags: html, css, background-color

I've been playing around with websites to figure out how they work. By downloading them and opening the in dream weaver cs6. But when I open the downloaded html file in my browser everything displays fine except the green background which is replaced with a default white one. Have a look.
http://www.bintrasher.com/index.html

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0036)http://www.bintrasher.com/index.html -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./Bintrasher1_files/style.css">
<title>Bintrasher</title>
<style type="text/css"></style></head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="top_banner"><img src="./Bintrasher1_files/dragons_den.gif" alt="dragons den"></div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./Bintrasher1_files/Bintrasher1.htm" class="selected">home</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bintrasher.com/domestic.html" class="main_link">domestic</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bintrasher.com/commercial.html" class="main_link">commercial</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bintrasher.com/videos.html" class="main_link">videos</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bintrasher.com/shop.html" class="main_link">shop</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bintrasher.com/contact.html" class="main_link">contact us</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left_column">
            <h1 class="header_home">Gain 40% more space in your wheelie bin!</h1>
            <p>
            Now with the Bin Trasher you can compact up to 40% of your waste to reduce overfilling and littering.
    </p><p>
    The sheer amount of waste produced by each household every week is increasing and the dangerous task of standing in your bin to squash your rubbish may be over!
    </p><p>
    We might just have the answer to your problem. The Bin Trasher is a simple gadget that compacts the waste and gives you 40% more space in your wheelie bin.


            </p>


        </div>
        <div id="right_column"><p>Watch our demonstration video now…</p>
        <object width="360" height="290"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/7aHbTdhtrho&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/7aHbTdhtrho&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="360" height="290"></object>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="col1">
                <p>
                <strong>Trade Enquiries Welcome</strong><br>
            <strong>Tel:</strong> 059 91 57629<br>
            <strong>Mobile:</strong> 087 206 9546<br>
            <strong>Email:</strong> <a href="maito:info@bintrasher.com">info@bintrasher.com</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
                <p>
                <strong class="firstline">Great Value at only </strong><br>
                <strong>€49.95</strong><br>
                <strong class="lastline">Including VAT</strong>
                </p>
        </div>
        <div id="col3"><a href="http://www.bintrasher.com/shop.html"><img src="./Bintrasher1_files/buynow.gif"></a></div>
    </div>
    <p class="lower_left">Bin Trasher. 2010. All rights reserved    </p>
    <p class="lower_right">Terms &amp; Conditions  |  Privacy Policy  |  Site Map<br>
    <a href="http://www.idea.ie/" target="_blank"><img src="./Bintrasher1_files/headers_26.gif"></a></p>
</div>





</body></html>
```

css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

img{border:0;}

body {text-align:center; margin:23px 0; background:url(../images/bgr.gif); font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:0.8em; line-height:1.4em;}



p a{color:#CC0000;}
p a:hover{color:#3c671e;}

#container {width:931px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:left;}


#top_banner {height:149px; background:url(../images/top_banner.gif) bottom no-repeat; text-align:right;}

#nav {height:35px; background:url(../images/top_ban_bit.gif) no-repeat right #4a4a30; color:#FFFFFF;}
#nav ul{list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0 0 0 10px;}
#nav li{float:left;  padding:6px 0.9em 0 0.9em; font-size:1.2em;}

#content{background:#FFFFFF; overflow:hidden; border-bottom:dotted 2px #006633;}



#left_column{ float:left; width:460px; padding:30px 30px;}


#right_column{margin-left:520px; padding:30px 20px;}

#footer{clear:both; background:#FFFFFF; overflow:hidden; padding:10px 20px 10px 30px; }
#footer div{float:left; width:33%;}

#col1 strong {color:#3c671e; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:normal;}

#col2 strong {color:#5c8424; font-size:4em; line-height:1.2em;}
#col2 .firstline{color:#333333; font-size:1.6em;}
#col2 .lastline{font-size:1em; color:#333333;}

#col3 {text-align:right; padding-top:30px;}

.main_link {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;}
.main_link:hover, .selected{color:#669b41; text-decoration:none;}

p.lower_left{float:left; font-size:0.8em; color:#FFFFFF;}
p.lower_right{float:right; font-size:0.8em; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:right;}

.header_home{background:url(../images/heading_home.gif) no-repeat; width:456px; height:73px; text-indent:-5000px;}
.header_industrial{background:url(../images/heading_industrial.gif) no-repeat; width:456px; height:73px; text-indent:-5000px;}
```

There is probably a very easy answer because I'm very new to web development.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have background image downloaded.

Comment: so do you want that green background or not..?

Comment: I was just confused as to why the background color dosen't show when the rest of the images show. Where does it come from?

Comment: SuperYegorius showed it came from http://www.bintrasher.com/images/bgr.gif so I downloaded seperately and now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

background:url(../images/bgr.gif);

you need to write

background:url(http://www.bintrasher.com/images/bgr.gif);

Answer (score 2):

A reference (the css file) is missing, I guess. Do you have the same file structure like on the server? I bet it will work then.

Comment: I just "saved page as > webpage" how would I get that?